# Why 'Total Value' Field on Item Master is editable in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite

I observe that the **Total Value** field on Item Master is editable while creating a new item.

[SCREEN SHOT OF TOTAL VALUE FIELD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyYqr.png)

While NetSuite generates this amount by multiplying your purchase price and your quantity on hand. As user buy and sell additional inventory, NetSuite continues to calculate the total value.

When I create the item along with figure in total value, after saving the value vanishes. After doing transactions e.g. Inventory adjustments the Total value polutated based on 'Total qty * avg cost'

When I create the item along with figure in total value, after saving the value vanishes. After doing transactions e.g. Inventory adjustments the Total value polutated based on 'Total qty * avg cost'

So, why is it editable? is there any functionality behind?